# Uploading capture image and store it in a folder changing it's filename to be unique using the userID

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code from this reference https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/DOCS.md?fbclid=IwAR0Q3W5mw8qWlJEdiabmyZJiw7wGJ5YDPRl2Ej0IKF3GCt_78HXeqAEjI6Y

it will display the webcam and take snapshots and make it to an image element using the data_uri but the problem is I want to get that file and store it with a declared filename into a folder here's the script I use

```
<script src="webcam.js"></script> <!--source code script from github for webcam config-->

<div id="my_camera" style="width:320px; height:240px;"></div>
<div id="my_result"></div>

<script type=text/javascript>
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );

    function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        } );
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())">Take Snapshot</a>
```

I have a button called register that functions like get all information being input and store it into the database like username first name etc together with the image taken by snapshot, here's my upload script in uploading images from a folder and I want to use it as getting the image data_uri and store it in a folder when I click the register button

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once'database.php';
$uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
   //check if ang uploaded file allowed i upload//
    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
            if ($fileError == 0){
                    if ($fileSize < 1000000){
                    $fileNameNew = "profile".$uid.".".$fileActualExt;
                    $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                    $sql = "UPDATE profileimg SET status=0 WHERE userID ='$uid';";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    header("location:../pages/userpage.php");
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "Your file is too big";
                    }
            } else {
                echo "There was an error uploading you file!";
            }
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type";
    }

}
```

I'm going to use this function as stated in the documentation

```
Webcam.upload( data_uri, 'myscript.php', function(code, text) {
        // Upload complete!
        // 'code' will be the HTTP response code from the server, e.g. 200
        // 'text' will be the raw response content
    } );

} );
```

and have this in my php script

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'], 'webcam.jpg');
```

any idea how should I turn this script into the one I use above in my upload.php? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create image first by image src and then need to save that in a specific folder. You can follow below code:

```
file_put_contents("fileNameWithLocation.png",file_get_contents($imageSrc));
```

Here fileNameWithLocation.png will be `$fileNameNew = "profile".$uid.".".$fileActualExt; $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;` You need to make modification accordingly. And `$imageSrc` will be the image src which you can post via Ajax or form submission.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: so my img src is the data_uri sir?

Comment: all of that is in php script sir, I won't gonna touch anything in my javascript?

Comment: Connect with me over Skype: rohit.mittal54 so I can help you better.

Comment: I don't have a skype sir, can you show me how it's done maybe I can understand better

Comment: @dread it is hard then. Can you share your code with me over rohitmittaltech@gmail.com and I will check will revert to you with working example

Comment: okay sir, I skip the saving part I just want to change the data_uri into a image file and then put in this $qrcode = new Zxing\QrReader($_FILES['qrimage']['tmp_name']);

Comment: technically, I am trying to get a snapshot from qrcode then decode it, but I want the data_uri to be an image, I will send it to you